# Can people without a background in STEM go into the field of AI?

Tags: machine-learning

I've recently become very interested in the potential AI holds for the future of society. I believe it has the potential to truly alter the way we live our lives in the not-too-distant future. I've read around three dozen books by leading scholars and I've written my undergraduate thesis on the implications of AI for modern warfare and the international balance of power. With that in mind, I've started to think about a career related to AI and machine learning.

However, I have a bit of a problem considering my background as a humanities person. I'm about to finish my undergraduate studies in International Relations and I plan to get a master in a similar field. As someone with little background in Comp Sci/ Math/ Physics/ etc, how could someone go about working in a field like AI? I struggle to see what utility non-STEM people could offer to firms.

I hope I'm asking this in the right place considering this forum is mostly for technical questions.

Comment: You will end up gaining a background in math and comp sci anyway as you try to understand what's going on. Physics is entirely optional. BUT: AI research doesn't just have to mean the technical side. If I want to know something about ethical vs unethical AI, a philosopher is likely to have a better answer for me than a programmer. What exactly do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: If you want to invent better AI techniques then of course you will have to delve into the maths and computer science. If you want to think about whether we should allow corporations to use our personal data for AI training, then, well, you won't have to. In any case it will help to have a bit of hands-on experience with the technology so you understand what it can and can't do